# Bootstrap timepicker is not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, timepicker

I want to use bootstrap time picker in my code. I have created demo page for that but it is not working. Here is my code:

```
<!Doctype html>
  <html>
    <head>
         <link href="resources/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/bootstrap-timepicker.css">
    </head>
    <body>       
       <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-4">
      <input name="time" class="time form-control" >
      </div>       
      <script src="resources/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
      <script src="resources/js/bootstrap-timepicker.js"></script>
      <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
          $('.time').timepicker();   
        });
       </script>
    </body>
 </html>
```

What is wrong with my Code?

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? What is the output on the page?

Comment: No. there is no any error on console. On page load input box shows current time and if I click on that input box it resets to 12.00.

Comment: Which version of bootstrap-timepicker is it?

Answer (score 0):

Datepicker no longer appears to be part of the bootstrap deliverable (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/). Although there are working datepicker examples using previous versions of bootstrap (http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) I would suggest using a datepicker from the open source community that is based on bootstrap 3 (https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker) :-)